# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.transform.EnhancedJsonErrorUnmarshaller

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

When trying to connect to the secret manager my code is throwing this exception. I am trying to Create a Secrets Manager client.

```
AWSSecretsManager client = 
    AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(region)
        .build();
```

In `Pom.xml` have added the following dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.965</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.965</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.965</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon suggests moving to the AWS SDK for Java V2. You can find Secret Manager V2 code in [Github here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/secretsmanager/src/main/java/com/example/secrets).

The POM file that contains the dependencies is located  in Github in the SecretManager folder.

V2 code has been tested many times and this code works:

```
package com.example.secrets;

//snippet-start:[secretsmanager.java2.create_secret.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.SecretsManagerClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.CreateSecretRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.CreateSecretResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.model.SecretsManagerException;
//snippet-end:[secretsmanager.java2.create_secret.import]

/**
 * To run this AWS code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your AWS credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 *https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */


public class CreateSecret {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    CreateSecret  <secretName> <secretValue> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    secretName - the name of the secret (for example, tutorials/MyFirstSecret). \n"+
                "    secretValue - the secret value. \n";

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String secretName = args[0];
        String secretValue= args[1];

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        SecretsManagerClient secretsClient = SecretsManagerClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

       String secretARN = createNewSecret(secretsClient, secretName, secretValue);
       System.out.println("The secret ARN is "+ secretARN);
       secretsClient.close();
    }

    //snippet-start:[secretsmanager.java2.create_secret.main]
    public static String createNewSecret( SecretsManagerClient secretsClient, String secretName, String secretValue) {

        try {
            CreateSecretRequest secretRequest = CreateSecretRequest.builder()
                .name(secretName)
                .description("This secret was created by the AWS Secret Manager Java API")
                .secretString(secretValue)
                .build();

            CreateSecretResponse secretResponse = secretsClient.createSecret(secretRequest);
            return secretResponse.arn();

        } catch (SecretsManagerException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }
    //snippet-end:[secretsmanager.java2.create_secret.main]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided by @smac2020 was not helpful for me, as I was not dealing with secrets, but AWS Cognito.
And this is what I found out - might be helpful for someone in the future

I got this error while I updated to the latest version of *cognitoip* `1.12.167`

```
   implementation group:  'io.awspring.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config', version: 1.12.167
```

This automatically downloads/is bundled with an **OLD VERSION** of *aws-java-sdk-core* and *jmespath-java* dependenies.
[image: screenshot of the how it came]

The `EnhancedJsonErrorUnmarshaller` is a new class with the latest version of *aws-java-sdk-core*, which was not in the default version that *cognitoip* was bundled with.

**Solution**: Update the *aws-java-sdk-core* manually to match the version of *cognitoip*.

```
 implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-core', version: '1.12.167'
```

This has the `EnhancedJsonErrorUnmarshaller` in it.
[image]